# How do i exclude a single secret from truffleHog scan in pipeline?

Tags: github, security, scanning, secret-key

Eg.: I have a file `mycode.py` which contains 2 secrets

```
myfakesecret : "ANSAJHSAKDKDMKADKAMCKSMKSMCKSCC"
MyOriginalSecret: "H%&&^DBSHDBHBBBS%^&&&DSD2343"
```

I want to ignore myfakesecret but not MyOriginalSecret in truffleHog scan.

If I use  `--exclude_paths exclude-patterns.txt` where `exclude-patterns.txt` contains `mycode.py` then truffle hog scan will ignore both secrets.

Can I specify a secret hash or name or any other way to exclude secret not complete file so that it should ignore a particular secret?

Answer (score -2):

Ideally, your code does not include the sensitive secret at all.
That way, truffleHog scan has nothing to ignore/exclude.

`mycode.py` should read that secret from a file/source *outside* the repository, at runtime (when you are executing the program).

> I understand, best practice is not to put sensitive secrets in code. Due to some testing constraints, the developer needs to put "myfakesecret" in the code itself. It is causing pipeline failure, I am looking for a way here like .gitignore if I can put the secret name in exclude file then scan should skip that secret.

It is understood that under certain testing conditions, having '`myfakesecret`' within the code is necessary, which is causing pipeline failures.

While truffleHog does not provide a direct mechanism akin to '`.gitignore`' to exclude specific secrets by name, a potential workaround could be to isolate the version of '`mycode.py`' containing '`myfakesecret`' in a specific branch, and maintain a 'clean' version in the main branch where the scanning occurs.

Alternatively, a custom script could be developed to handle the exclusion of '`myfakesecret`' during the truffleHog scan.

Comment: I understand, best practice is not to put sensitive secrets in code. Due to some testing constraints, the developer needs to put "myfakesecret" in the code itself.  It is causing pipeline failure, I am looking for a way here like .gitignore if I can put the secret name in exclude file then scan should skip that secret.

Comment: @SahilArora Is it possible to isolate that version of the file in a specific branch, and have a "clean" version of the same file in the main branch, where the scanning occurs?

Comment: Actually not !! We are running it on all the branches and if it is fake/expired then we don't mind to keep in the main branch too.